# Entity framework multiple object relation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table with 2 foreignkeys to the same parent table, Edge.StartStationId and Edge.EndStationId.

I am trying to map theese to objets in entity framework, but can't find a workaround which seems to fix the problem.
I've found some solutions using 2 collections on the parent (Station), which I'm not interested in.

Station (parent) class:

```
public partial class Station
{
    public Station()
    {
        this.Reservations = new List<Reservation>();
        this.StationMaintenances = new List<StationMaintenance>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal StationLat { get; set; }
    public decimal StationLong { get; set; }
    public bool IsOperational { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual BatteryStorage BatteryStorages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StationMaintenance> StationMaintenances { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
    public virtual StationType StationType { get; set; }
}
```

Edge (child) class:

```
public partial class Edge
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int StartStationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Station StartStation { get; set; }
    public int EndStationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Station EndStation { get; set; }
    public decimal Distance { get; set; }
    public decimal Time { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

The edge map class, which is added in OnModelCreating.

```
public EdgeMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

    // Properties
    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Edges");
    this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
    this.Property(t => t.StartStationId).HasColumnName("StartStationId");
    this.Property(t => t.EndStationId).HasColumnName("EndStationId");
    this.Property(t => t.Distance).HasColumnName("Distance");
    this.Property(t => t.Time).HasColumnName("Time");
    this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");

    // Relationships
    //this.HasOptional(t => t.StartStation)
    //    .WithMany(t => t.Edges)
    //    .HasForeignKey(d => d.StarStationId);
    //this.HasOptional(t => t.EndStation)
    //    .WithMany(t => t.Edges)
    //    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EndStationId);
}
```

Exception:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Edge_EndStation_Target' in relationship 'Edge_EndStation'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Comment: I think EF could get confused when persisting changes to Edges collection, so I don't think EF would let you do this. I think you may end up with two edges collection or with a non-virtual Edges collection where you load the edges from the station collections manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think the particular error you posted is complaining about the `HasOptional`.  Since the foreign keys (`StartStationId` and `EndStationId`) are non-nullable, it's expecting a required mapping.  Try changing it to `HasRequired`, or change the type of `StartStationId` and `EndStationId` to `int?` so that it knows the navigation properties can be null.

As for the `Edges` collection, what should it contain?  Any `Edge` that references the `Station` with either the `StartStationId` or `EndStationId` values?  If so, I don't think you can do that with a single collection.

Comment: The edge collection should contain the edges where the StationId equals StartStationId. How ever, as you said this might not be possible what I want. I ended up removing the StartStation object from Edge, and only adding the reference to EndStation.

Comment: I think that should be possible.  If you're still working on it, try something like `this.HasOptional(t => t.StartStation).WithMany(t => t.Edges).HasForeignKey(d => d.StartStationId);` and then `this.HasOptional(t => EndStation).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.EndStationId)`.